# Text File Reading Error with multiple delimiter JAVA

Tags: java, object, text-files, stringtokenizer

[image: Cars.txt]

This is the text file I want to read and display on console. Here are my codes for reading the file:

```
 public class CarMain
 {
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File("Cars.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "", fullName;
        String[] arrName = null;
        Car[] c = new Car[3];
        String name, ic, manufacturer, model;
        int num = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {                      
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            name = st.nextToken();  

            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line,"://;");
            ic = st2.nextToken();
            manufacturer = st2.nextToken();
            model = st2.nextToken();


            c[num] = new Car(name,ic, manufacturer, model);

            num++;

        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(c[i].toString());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error opening file");
    }
   }
}
```

then I get this output:

[image]

It seems that it doesn't display the model name after ";" and the data is not in the right place.

My expected output is like this:

```
 Name: Fatimah Zahra Ali
 IC: 860802105012
 Manufacturer: Proton
 Model: Perdana
        .
        .
        .
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `st2` is a new **tokenizer**. You should read the tokens from `st2` as follows:

```
 StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line,"://;");
 name = st2.nextToken(); // first token
 ic = st2.nextToken();   // second 
 manufacturer = st2.nextToken(); // third 
 model = st2.nextToken(); // fourth
```

The first tokenizer is not required.

Comment: it worked when print out the name but storing it in Car(name,ic,manufacturer,model) the name is not showing as shown below.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have put all st2 but the name is missing.